# Repair Fragments in CGPathes of Cocoa Touch / Core Graphics

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, drawing, core-animation, core-graphics

I have an unusual problem that caused my mind to stuck. I have created a drawing application that uses CGPathes to be created by a pen tool on the fly via the following view controller code.

```
@implementation WWLGrabManager
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touchesIgnore withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
     currentPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
     CGPathMoveToPoint(currentPath, NULL, pt.x, pt.y); 
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touchesIgnore withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
     CGPathAddLineToPoint(currentPath, NULL, pt.x, pt.y);
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    currentPath = [self newSmoothedPathWithPath:currentPath];
}
@end
```

After the drawing I iterate once again over the CGPath in order to smooth the drawn edges of the path. This shall make the path to not look so ugly by building the middle of each three points and applying a curve to each point. The code for smoothing edges mainly consists of the following pseudo code:

```
-(CGMutablePathRef)newSmoothedPathWithPath:(CGPathRef)path {
      // This is pseudo code
      CGMutablePathRef newPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
      foreach (CGPoint point in path)
            CGPathAddCurveToPoint(newPath, NULL, 
                    ctrlPt1.x,ctrlPt1.y,ctrlPt2.x,ctrlPt2.y,
                    ((*preLastPoint).x + (*lastPoint).x + (point).x)/3, 
                    ((*preLastPoint).y + (*lastPoint).y + (point).y)/3); 
      }
      return newPath;
 }
```

Now, after applying the smoothing function, the new CGPath causes fragments like in the [picture here](http://eglador.de/fragments.png). I have double checked the control points, but I cannot figure out why this is happening.

For debugging reasons I have printed out a log of the CGPathes points and control points below.

```
 MainPoint //      ControlPoint1 //  ControlPoint2

 66.00, 91.00 //   67.00,87.00 //    64.25,95.75 
 59.00,110.00 //   60.75,105.25 //   58.00,113.75 
 55.00,125.00 //   56.00,121.25 //   54.00,128.75 
 51.00,140.00 //   52.00,136.25 //   50.25,144.25 
 48.00,157.00 //   48.75,152.75 //   47.25,161.00 
 45.00,173.00 //   45.75,169.00 //   44.75,176.75 
 44.00,188.00 //   44.25,184.25 //   43.75,191.75 
 43.00,203.00 //   43.25,199.25 //   43.00,207.00 
 43.00,219.00 //   43.00,215.00 //   43.00,223.00 
 43.00,235.00 //   43.00,231.00 //   43.00,239.25 
 43.00,252.00 //   43.00,247.75 //   43.00,256.00 
 43.00,268.00 //   43.00,264.00 //   44.25,272.00 
 48.00,284.00 //   46.75,280.00 //   49.50,287.50 
 54.00,298.00 //   52.50,294.50 //   56.75,300.75 
 65.00,309.00 //   62.25,306.25 //   68.75,310.75 
 80.00,316.00 //   76.25,314.25 //   84.00,316.50 
 96.00,318.00 //   92.00,317.50 //   101.50,318.25 
 118.00,319.00 //  112.50,318.75 //  124.75,319.00 
 145.00,319.00 //  138.25,319.00 //  151.25,319.00 
 170.00,319.00 //  163.75,319.00 //  175.50,318.25 
 192.00,316.00 //  186.50,316.75 //  199.50,314.00 
 222.00,308.00 //  214.50,310.00 //  226.75,306.75 
 241.00,303.00 //  236.25,304.25 //  245.00,301.75 
 257.00,298.00 //  253.00,299.25 //  260.50,295.75 
 271.00,289.00 //  267.50,291.25 //  273.25,285.25 
 280.00,274.00 //  277.75,277.75 //  280.50,270.25 
 282.00,259.00 //  281.50,262.75 //  282.00,254.50 
 282.00,241.00 //  282.00,245.50 //  280.50,237.25 
 276.00,226.00 //  277.50,229.75 //  273.50,222.75 
 266.00,213.00 //  268.50,216.25 //  263.00,208.75 
 254.00,196.00 //  257.00,200.25 //  249.75,192.50 
 237.00,182.00 //  241.25,185.50 //  234.00,179.75 
 225.00,173.00 //  228.00,175.25 //  221.75,170.50 
 212.00,163.00 //  215.25,165.50 //  208.50,160.25 
 198.00,152.00 //  201.50,154.75 //  194.00,148.75 
 182.00,139.00 //  186.00,142.25 //  178.00,136.75 
 166.00,130.00 //  170.00,132.25 //  162.25,128.50
```

**Update:** I used the algorithm described in [this link](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Graphics/Jean-YvesQueinecBezierCurves.htm), which was translated to Objective-C as follows:

```
 CGPoint ctrl2 = controlPointForPoints(*lastPoint,*preLastPoint,currentPoint);
 CGPoint ctrl1 = controlPointForPoints(*lastPoint,currentPoint,*preLastPoint);

 static CGPoint controlPointForPoints(CGPoint pt, CGPoint pre, CGPoint post) {
     CGPoint ctrlPt = CGPointMake(
         middleOfPoints(middleOfPoints(pt.x, pre.x), middleOfPoints(symmetryOfPoints(pt.x, post.x), pt.x)),
         middleOfPoints(middleOfPoints(pt.y, pre.y), middleOfPoints(symmetryOfPoints(pt.y, post.y), pt.y))
     );

     return ctrlPt;
 }

 static float symmetryOfPoints(float a,float b) {
     return a - ((b-a)*smoothingFactor) / 100.0;
 }

 static float middleOfPoints(float a, float b) {
     return (a+b) / 2.0;
 }
```

However, exchanging the two control points does not lead to satisfactory results but increases the number of fragments enourmously. I'd appreciate any further help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, your code doesn't show how the control points of the smoothed path are calculated. But they are the problem. Most of them are on the wrong side of the start or end point of a curve segment. As a consequence, your path makes a very tight loop or S curve at many main points.

Another indication of this is that while the path generally turns left, many path segments are to the right.

I don't quite understand why you have these white half circles. It seems the even-odd rule is used to draw the path instead of the non-zero winding rule, which probably cannot be changed. Anyway, the problem will disappear if you fix the above problem.

Comment: I have updated the post above to describe how the control points were calculated.

Comment: The pieces of your algorithm are difficult to understand. You'll have to check again whether you're passing the correct coordinates to the correct arguments of your methods. In most cases, the control points should lie more or less between two consecutive main points. The odd thing in your code is that algorithm seems to require for main points to calculate the control points, yet your code only deals with three at a time.

Comment: What I really don't understand is that each control point seems to look reasonable and always lies between two main points. The left control point (ControlPoint1) always lies between the point and the point before. The right control point (ControlPoint2) always lies between the point and the point after. Then, what is the reason for the artifacts?

I would appreciate if somebody can help me understanding this.

Comment: What you describe is exactly the mistake you made. Control point 1 is not supposed to lie between the point and the point before. And neither is control point 2. You should more or less have ascending (or descending) coordinates for the sequence: main point, control point 1, control point 2, main point, control point 1 etc.